# How can I change the color of an histogram label icon?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, bar-chart

Here's the code. However, the histogram has a black icon as a label. How can I change it to red or to the gradient of colors 'hot'. I know I changed the bars colors to that of the gradient 'hot' however I don't want a black label for the histogram since I want to distinguish it from the analytical one.

```
import math, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, random 

def probability(x):

    #wavefunction n=0 evaluated at position x
    psi_0_x=math.exp(-x ** 2 / 2.0) / math.pi ** 0.25

    #probability n=0 to be at position x
    psi_0_x_squared= psi_0_x**2

    return psi_0_x_squared

data_x=[0]
x = 0.0        #starts at position 0
delta = 0.5    #stepsize
trial_steps=1000000

for t in range(trial_steps):

    #displace x by delta
    x_new = x + random.uniform(-delta, delta) 

    #selecciono un numero entre 0 y 1 (incluye acceptance y rejection probability). Metropolis!
    #probabilidad de estar en nuevo sitio/probabilidad de quedarme en el sitio anterior 
    if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < probability(x_new)/probability(x):

        #me muevo si la condicion es cierta (está en el accepted range)
        x = x_new 
    data_x.append(x)

#histogram
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('hot') 
n, bins, patches= plt.hist(data_x, bins=100, normed=True, color='r',label='Histogram')
for height, p in zip(n, patches):
    plt.setp(p, 'facecolor', cm(height))

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('$Probability =|\psi_0(x)|^2$')

#general analytical formula
x_grid = [a / 100.0 for a in range(-300,301)]
Prob = [probability(position) for position in x_grid]
plt.plot(x_grid, Prob, linewidth=1.5, color='k', label='Analytical')

plt.title("Position's probability density $|\psi_0(x)|^2$ for a harmonic oscillator.")
plt.savefig('ground_probability_x.png')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is that put the generating the `legend` before the updating of `facecolor` of the `hist`. Also, I noticed a small problem, why you save the figure even before the generating of the `legend`? Here is the fixed code and result:

```
import math, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, random 

def probability(x):

    #wavefunction n=0 evaluated at position x
    psi_0_x=math.exp(-x ** 2 / 2.0) / math.pi ** 0.25

    #probability n=0 to be at position x
    psi_0_x_squared= psi_0_x**2

    return psi_0_x_squared

data_x=[0]
x = 0.0        #starts at position 0
delta = 0.5    #stepsize
trial_steps=1000000

for t in range(trial_steps):

    #displace x by delta
    x_new = x + random.uniform(-delta, delta) 

    #selecciono un numero entre 0 y 1 (incluye acceptance y rejection probability). Metropolis!
    #probabilidad de estar en nuevo sitio/probabilidad de quedarme en el sitio anterior 
    if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < probability(x_new)/probability(x):

        #me muevo si la condicion es cierta (está en el accepted range)
        x = x_new 
    data_x.append(x)

#histogram
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('hot') 
n, bins, patches= plt.hist(data_x, bins=100, normed=True, color='r',label='Histogram')


plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('$Probability =|\psi_0(x)|^2$')

#general analytical formula
x_grid = [a / 100.0 for a in range(-300,301)]
Prob = [probability(position) for position in x_grid]
plt.plot(x_grid, Prob, linewidth=1.5, color='k', label='Analytical')
plt.title("Position's probability density $|\psi_0(x)|^2$ for a harmonic oscillator.")
# first legend, then updating the facecolor
plt.legend()
for height, p in zip(n, patches):
    plt.setp(p, 'facecolor', cm(height))
# finally save the figure
plt.savefig('ground_probability_x.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Hope it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Yep you're right about the saving part. And thanks for your help :)